# Cannot resolve the certain symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

My code seems fine but after I put I in the parenthesis it turned red saying it can't be resolved. Do I have something I forgot? It is fine?

```
if (success) {
   for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++);
  {
          JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  }
```

Comment: When you are complaining about some error message, it's generally a good idea to include that error message. That way, I could just answer your question instead of asking you for the exact message, which would then tell me exactly what you forgot to do.

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the `for` loop line. The `;` ends the loop, and hence ends the scope where `i` is declared, which means that `i` doesn't exist inside the following block.

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax of the for loop.
it should look something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //loop code
}
```